# Как обработать информацию с поля модели и разделить его на текст и фото и вывести обратно, фото нужно сгруппировать и показать в виде слайда

Tags: python, django

Как обработать информацию с поля модели и разделить его на текст и фото и вывести обратно, фото нужно сгруппировать и показать в виде слайда
вот есть такая модель для Поста

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Пост')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, verbose_name='url', unique=True)
    #author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Кол-во просмотров')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='posts')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='posts')
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Важная новость')
    #images = models.ManyToManyField('Image', blank=True, related_name='posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

представление для поста чтобы просмотреть пост

```
class GetPost(DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_template_names(self):
        category_slug = self.object.category.slug
        if category_slug == 'longridder':
            return ['news/longrid-detail.html']
        else:
            return ['news/news-detail.html']

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.object.views = F('views') + 1
        self.object.save()
        self.object.refresh_from_db()

        # Проверяем наличие фотографии перед добавлением в контекст
        if self.object.photo:
            context['background_image'] = self.object.photo.url
        else:
            context['background_image'] = '{% static "images/default-bg.jpg" %}'

        return context
```

я это представление модифицировал для того чтобы разделить с поля контент информацию на текстовую и фото вот таким образом:

```
class GetPost(DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_template_names(self):
        category_slug = self.object.category.slug
        if category_slug == 'longridder':
            return ['news/longrid-detail.html']
        else:
            return ['news/news-detail.html']

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        content = self.object.content

        # Используем регулярное выражение для поиска всех ссылок на изображения в контенте
        image_paths = re.findall(r'/media/uploads/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/[^\s]+.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)', content)

        # Удаляем найденные ссылки на изображения из контента
        text_content = re.sub(r'/media/uploads/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/[^\s]+', '', content)

        # Разделяем текст и изображения на параграфы и пути к изображениям
        text_paragraphs = text_content.strip().split('\n')
        image_paths = [image_path for image_path in image_paths if image_path]  # Отфильтровываем пустые строки

        # Сохраняем порядок ввода
        combined_content = list(zip(text_paragraphs, image_paths))

        # Добавляем текст и изображения в контекст
        context['combined_content'] = combined_content

        # Подсчет количества статей пользователя
        author = self.object.author
        article_count = Post.objects.filter(author=author).count()
        context['article_count'] = article_count

        context['background_image'] = self.object.photo.url if self.object.photo else '{% static "images/default-bg.jpg" %}'
        return context
```

это представление обрабатывает данные с поля контент и делит на текст и фото, так же выводит в том же порядке что было при создании
пост создается через админку джанги
при создании поста для поля контент испльзуется ck-editor

```
class PostAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostAdminForm
    inlines = [ImageInline]
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'slug', 'is_featured', 'created_at', 'get_photo', 'views', 'author_name')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'title')
    search_fields = ('title',)
    list_filter = ('category',)
    readonly_fields = ('views', 'created_at', 'get_photo', 'author_name')
    fields = ('title', 'slug', 'category', 'is_featured', 'tags', 'content', 'photo', 'get_photo', 'views',
              'created_at', 'author_name')

    def get_photo(self, obj):
        if obj.photo:
            return mark_safe(f'<img src="{obj.photo.url}" width="50"')
        return '-'

    get_photo.short_description = 'Фото'

    def author_name(self, obj):
        return obj.author.username

    author_name.short_description = 'Автор'

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Если пост только создается (не изменяется), устанавливаем текущего пользователя как автора
        if not change:
            obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
```

пост может создаваться таким образом, вводим текст, далее фотографии, далее текст, далее фотки, нужно вывести в таком же порядке, но сгруппировав фотки и показав их в виде слайда, если тело поля контент не содержит фотки то просто вывести что есть.
в данный момент модифицированное представление делит на текст и фото и выводит просто, но фотки сгруппировать не получается. заранее благодарю всех кто обратит внимание и подскажет как решить это.